# A clearance between A and B or C?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to describe the positional relationships between 3 objects.

- A and B are 1 m apart
- A and C are 1 m apart

Can I say like this?

- Provide a 1m clearance between A and B or C.

Or is there some other ways to describe it in one sentence?

Answer (score 1):

As this looks like a "specfication" it would be good to have a little redundancy:

> ... between A and B,  or between A and C

Use that if you only need one of those clearances; if it is okay for A to be closer than 1m to B provided it is more than one metre from C

> ... between A and B, and between A and C.

Use that if you need both clearances to be greater than one metre.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. So is it okay for me to say "...between A and B, and between A and C to avoid hitting with each other"?

Comment: Yes in principle, but perhaps "to avoid collisions" would be more formal.